# Remove first two words from a string

Tags: php, cpu-word, truncate

I have a string:

```
$string = "R 124 This is my message";
```

At times, the string may change, such as:

```
$string = "R 1345255 This is another message";
```

Using PHP, what's the best way to remove the first two "words" (e.g., the initial "R" and then the subsequent numbers)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$result = preg_replace('/^R \\d+ /', '', $string, 1);
```

or (if you want your spaces to be written in a more visible style)

```
$result = preg_replace('/^R\\x20\\d+\\x20/', '', $string, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Jacco, this is what I was looking for.  

+1 for Pascal, as there was some good 'teaching' information in there for me!

Comment: This would slightly fail if someone were to use double spacing, I'd probably suggest

$result = preg_replace('/^R\s\d+\s/', '', $string, 1);

Answer (score 16):

```
$string = explode (' ', $string, 3);
$string = $string[2];
```

Must be much faster than regexes.

Comment: Fixed typo in string index in second line (was 3 instead of 2).

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to explode the string in "words", using [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) or [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) *(depending on the complexity of the words separators : are they always one space ? )*

For instance :

```
$string = "R 124 This is my message";
$words = explode(' ', $string);
var_dump($words);
```

You'd get an array like this one :

```
array
  0 => string 'R' (length=1)
  1 => string '124' (length=3)
  2 => string 'This' (length=4)
  3 => string 'is' (length=2)
  4 => string 'my' (length=2)
  5 => string 'message' (length=7)
```

Then, with [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice), you keep only the words you want (not the first two ones) :

```
$to_keep = array_slice($words, 2);
var_dump($to_keep);
```

Which gives :

```
array
  0 => string 'This' (length=4)
  1 => string 'is' (length=2)
  2 => string 'my' (length=2)
  3 => string 'message' (length=7)
```

And, finally, you put the pieces together :

```
$final_string = implode(' ', $to_keep);
var_dump($final_string);
```

Which gives...

```
string 'This is my message' (length=18)
```

And, if necessary, it allows you to do couple of manipulations on the words before joining them back together :-)

*Actually, this is the reason why you might choose that solution, which is a bit longer that using only `explode` and/or `preg_split` ^^*

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/^\\w+\\s\\d+\\s(.*)/", '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/^R\s+\d+\s*/', '', $string);
```