# Remove everything before certain point of a string

Tags: php, string, truncate

I have stored strings under `name` column in my database like so:

`materials`

```
302 / 1001 / 8 ДЮБЕЛ 8/60
304 / 1001 / 32 НИВИЛИР АЛУМИНИЕВ AV 180
232 / 1004 / 34 РЕДУЦИР-ВЕНТИЛ ЗА КИСЛОРОД А ТИП
549 / 1034 / 10051 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 3/4"
455 / 1034 / 10053 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 1 1/4"
603 / 7000 / 10086 ТРЪБА ПОДЦИНКОВАНА 2"
333 / 4001 / 10101 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 25 ММ.
344 / 1002 / 10102 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 20 ММ.
```

The name of the material begins after the 3rd number and I'd like to remove everything before the actual name including the whitespace.

The new table should look like this:

`materials`

```
ДЮБЕЛ 8/60
НИВИЛИР АЛУМИНИЕВ AV 180
РЕДУЦИР-ВЕНТИЛ ЗА КИСЛОРОД А ТИП
ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 3/4"
НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 1 1/4"
ПОДЦИНКОВАНА 2"
ТРЪБА ППР Ф 25 ММ.
ТРЪБА ППР Ф 20 ММ.
```

I have tried to achieve this in a few ways but none of them worked as expected.
`strstr` for example removes everything before an occurrence like `/` but it only removes the first number.
Regular expressions didn't work either.

Comment: 'Regular expressions didn't work either' - perhaps you could share what you tried and we could fix that?

Comment: `explode()` by space and get rid of the first 5 parts?

Comment: Also, I note that you're attempting to do this in PHP.  It might be easier to do this directly in the database (depending on what kind of database you have).  Perhaps you could share some details?

Comment: Remove first n words from a string: [Remove first two words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225948/2943403)

Comment: [Remove first two words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225948/2943403)

Comment: [`var_export(preg_replace('/^\Pl+/', '', $array));`](https://3v4l.org/S7t3l) as shown by https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880834/2943403

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the numbers and slashes before the text (letters), you can do as in the example:

```
<?php

// Sample array of strings
$originalStrings = [
    "302 / 1001 / 8 ДЮБЕЛ 8/60",
    "304 / 1001 / 32 НИВИЛИР АЛУМИНИЕВ AV 180",
    "232 / 1004 / 34 РЕДУЦИР-ВЕНТИЛ ЗА КИСЛОРОД А ТИП",
    "549 / 1034 / 10051 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 3/4\"",
    "455 / 1034 / 10053 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 1 1/4\"",
    "603 / 7000 / 10086 ТРЪБА ПОДЦИНКОВАНА 2\"",
    "333 / 4001 / 10101 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 25 ММ.",
    "344 / 1002 / 10102 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 20 ММ."
];

// Process each string
foreach ($originalStrings as $originalString) {
    // Use regular expression to match and replace unnecessary numbers
    $result = preg_replace('/^[0-9\s\/]+/', '', $originalString);
    
    echo $result . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

This code uses preg_replace to replace all leading numbers, whitespace and slashes with an empty string. The result is the modified strings without the unnecessary numbers before the text.

Comment: Try to check it in the online PHP compiler (it looks good from my side).

Comment: Can I suggest you add a space at the end of the pattern?  That way it won't remove text that happens to start with a number

Comment: Rob's advice to append a space after the character class was nonsense -- the character class contains `\s` already. https://3v4l.org/J34Pe

Answer (score -1):

Explode with a field count, and trim the whitespace.

```php
$input = <<<_E_
302 / 1001 / 8 ДЮБЕЛ 8/60
304 / 1001 / 32 НИВИЛИР АЛУМИНИЕВ AV 180
232 / 1004 / 34 РЕДУЦИР-ВЕНТИЛ ЗА КИСЛОРОД А ТИП
549 / 1034 / 10051 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 3/4"
455 / 1034 / 10053 ТРЪБА НЕРЪЖДАЕМА ШЕВНА 1 1/4"
603 / 7000 / 10086 ТРЪБА ПОДЦИНКОВАНА 2"
333 / 4001 / 10101 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 25 ММ.
344 / 1002 / 10102 ТРЪБА ППР Ф 20 ММ.
_E_;

$lines = explode("\n", $input);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    var_dump(array_map('trim', explode('/', $line, 3)));
}
```

Comment: Use ' / ' as a separator and you won't need to trim anymore.